# Loop repeats twice when I run the program

Tags: java, loops

I'm a new programmer and attempted to make a program which adds all user inputted numbers. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Adding
{
private int numOfInt, newInt;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Adding
 */
public Adding()
{
    // initialise instance variables
    Scanner console = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.print("How many integers will be added?");
    numOfInt = console.nextInt();
    newInt = 0;
}
public int addIntegers()
{
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while( count <= numOfInt )
    {
        System.out.println("The count is: " + count + " and the current sum is: " + sum);
        count = count + 1;
        Scanner console = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
        newInt = console.nextInt();
        sum = sum + newInt;
    }
    return sum;
}
public void displaySum()
{
            System.out.println("the sum is " + this.addIntegers());
}
}
```

This is the second class for the main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class AddingMain
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
   Adding add = new Adding();
   add.addIntegers();
   add.displaySum();
}
}
```

However, the loop repeats twice (as can be seen in the input below, edited to save space) and actually ignores the first set of numbers entered:

> How many integers will be added?**3**
>
> The count is: 0 and the current sum is: 0
>
> Enter an integer: **1**
>
> The count is: 1 and the current sum is: 1
>
> Enter an integer: **2**
>
> The count is: 2 and the current sum is: 3
>
> Enter an integer: **3**
>
> The count is: 3 and the current sum is: 6
>
> Enter an integer: **1**
>
> The count is: 0 and the current sum is: 0
>
> Enter an integer: **2**
>
> The count is: 1 and the current sum is: 2
>
> Enter an integer: **3**
>
> The count is: 2 and the current sum is: 5
>
> Enter an integer: **4**
>
> The count is: 3 and the current sum is: 9
>
> Enter an integer: **5**
>
> the sum is 14

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: How many times is the loop supposed to repeat?

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use a debugger to step through your code to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Each call to `addIntegers` will perform the loop once. Count the number of `addIntegers` calls in your code.

Comment: Also, by using `<=` in the while loop, you execute it 4 times when `numOfInt` is 3. You probably meant to use `<`.

Answer (score 4):

The loop repeats twice because you are calling `addIntegers()` twice.

The very first time you called `addIntegers()` by writing `add.addIntegers();`
 and the next time you called `addIntegers()` by writing  `System.out.println("the sum is " + this.addIntegers());` .

`this.addIntegers()` is again calling the method `addIntegers()`.

> Extra Suggestion

You can use the scanner object by just instantiating the Scanner object at class level i.e you dont need to instantiate scanner object twice in your code.

You can go like this--

```
public class Adding
{
private int numOfInt, newInt;
Scanner console = new Scanner( System.in );
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `addIntegers` is called twice, one time in the `main` and one time in `displaySum`. So, the loop is executed twice, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 add.addIntegers(); // invoke 1st time
 add.displaySum();  // invoke 2nd time
```

You invoked `addIntegers()` explicitly once, and it is invoked by `displaySum()` the 2nd time

adding integers and display sum are two different responsibilities, you'd better split them into 2 functions. Makes `displaySum()` display sum only other than adding integers. You can create an instance variable `sum` in Class `Adding`, and change displaySum() to

```
public int displaySum(){
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the addInteger() from the main() , so that it is only called once, and you get your desired output .